# How to compute a negative Sobolev norm with Matlab

Tags: matlab, calculus, numerical-analysis

Let the torus T^2 be the domain [0,1)^2 in R^2 with periodic boundary conditions. In general, the negative Sobolev norm H^(-1) of a function f defined on the torus can be computed as:

- a dual norm from the H^1 space, i.e. H^(-1) is defined to be de dual of H^1 (note: we say g is in H^1 if grad g is in L^2).
- in terms of the Fourier transform Ff like the sum over all frequencies k in Z^2 without k=(0,0) of |Ff(k)|^2/|k|^2.

I am running some numerical experiments in Matlab and I would like to compute the H^(-1) norm of some functions that I have obtained numerically and hence I have defined in a finite set of discrete points. The most straightforward way to compute it might be by means of the command [fft2](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html), since in the end my 2D function is just described by a matrix. My problem is that I do not know how the frequencies are labelled by this command, would it be enough to do

```
    Ff = fft2(f);
    sob_norm = 0;
    for i=1:L
        for j=1:L
            if i==1 && j==1
                sob_norm = sob_norm;
            else
                sob_norm = sob_norm + norm([i-1,j-1])^(-2)*norm(Ff(i,j))^2;
            end
        end
    end
```

or should I scale the 1/|k|^2 in a different way? I guess there is something I am not understanding correctly because the scale of the norm is much bigger than it should.

I apologize whether this is not the most appropriate forum to ask about this, any help about a more convenient place it is very much appreciated too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The MATLAB fft frequency convention is the first entry is 0 frequency and then increases to fs/2 in the middle of the result.  Then the frequency changes to -fs/2 increasing back to the entry prior to 0 at the end of the vector.  If you want monotonic increase from -fs/2 to +fs/2 apply fftshift to  the output of your fft.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome by the way, do you have any clue about how this split is made when I have an even number of points in my array?

Comment: An example: f = [0 1 2 3 -4 -3 -2 -1];  fftshift(f) = [-4 -3 -2  -1 0 1 2 3];